# Modify settings.ADMINS for a particular Django exception?

Tags: python, django, exception

We have a particular exception that we'd like to notify another team of via Django's default error report email. How would I do that? I'd imagine modifying the `settings.ADMIN` variable on this particular exception would do the trick, but I'm not sure how exactly I'd do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like it.
In my case, I have a same source code but for two app(restful api for dev and admin site for admin).
It have a different setting and with your case is different about admin address will be using to send notify mail

You can do that without any problem. so you have to modify wsig.py file

I have a example for this. I have a settings_api.py and settings_admin.py. You can run web app for development you case using

```
python manage.py runserver --settings={{name_project}}.settings_{{admin|api}} 0.0.0.0:8080
```

with name_project is name of you project

admin|api is suffix of setting file. in your case is ADMIN

If you want to deploy on production you have to change it on wsgi.py file. Change name of setting file which you want load.